# The way to store float value(member variable) in NSArray or NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to store float value (member variable : change continue) in NSArray or NSMutableArray so, want to see NSLog form. I tried again and again, but failed.

Would you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean "want to see NSLog form"?

Answer (score 1):

That's why the `NSNumber` class is there:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.14f];
// or:
NSNumber *num = @(3.14f);
[mutableArray addObject:num];

NSLog(@"%f", [(NSNumber *)[mutableArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
```

Comment: I tried. But the log shown only 1 object

Comment: And why don't you read the documentation? Why don't you google? Why do you ask stupid questions?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I already tried to googling enough and now, I have no choice but to do.

Comment: There's a good tutorial here: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSMutableArray

Comment: Great answer, but you could do it with a shorter syntax.

Comment: @김해현 -Why would you expect more than one object?

Comment: The answer is correct. Also it could be possible to take advantage of the new literals syntax in this way: `NSNumber * num = @(3.14f)`

Comment: Also NSLog(@"%@", mutableArray[0]);

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store primitive types in an `NSArray`, you must first box (wrap) them in a NSObject instance, such as `NSNumber`.

```
float myVal = 5.5f;
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myVal], nil];
NSLog("some array: %@", arr);
```

Of course, you could just output a float directly using `NSLog(@"my value: %f", myVal)`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for another answer but I couldn't see that old and too long syntax:

```
NSArray* arr= @[ @1.0 ];
NSLog(@"%@",arr[0] );
```

Notice that you haven't to call [arr[0] floatValue], the description method will do it's job.

Comment: The only part that "shorter" is the `@1.0;`, and you can't use that notation on a variable.

Comment: You aren't right , I can use that notation and the difference was not only this if you looked well. But I made it even shorter.

Comment: I don't think so.Btw you also missed the [0] instead of objectAtIndex and missing floatValue using the %@ specifier.

Comment: The above syntax is legit. The first `@` will translate into an NSArray instantiation, while the `@1.0` will instantiate a `NSNumber` from the specified float.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - I agree it's technically legit, but it adds nothing to the discussion -- doesn't answer any outstanding question.

Comment: What you meant by "you can't use that notation on a variable"?